# Ruby gem for Mozenda

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

Has anyone worked with Mozenda in ruby on rails project before?
I am looking for gem or wrapper of Mozenda API.
Searched online there were two library '[mozenda](https://github.com/jefferyf/mozenda)' and '[mozenda-api](https://github.com/darrikmazey/mozenda-api)'.
Unfortunately, both cannot be found when i tried to install them.

Comment: install them as a git repo by adding to **Gemfile**: `gem 'mozenda', :git => 'https://github.com/jefferyf/mozenda'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install one of them as a git repo by adding the proper record into **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'mozenda', :git => 'https://github.com/jefferyf/mozenda.git'
```

or

```
gem 'mozenda-api', :git => 'https://github.com/darrikmazey/mozenda-api.git'
```

Then issue:

```
$ bundle install
```